# How to get numeric index of the equivalent key in associative array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var assoArray={
    "Test": 0,
    "Test 2": 2
}
```

In the above associative array, i could get value of Test2 by

```
var valofTest2 = assoArray["Test 2"]
```

how do i get the equivalent numeric index of "Test 2" ? would expect 1 as an output

PS: am new to JS

Comment: 1. It's an `Object`.  2. Order in `Object` is not guaranteed.

Comment: that index is not dependable and there is no guranteed order of processing the keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one.

Before the latest specification updates (ES6), the order of keys in an object was entirely undefined and could return in a different order every time.

With ES6, the order is defined as the order they were added in, so you can get close with something like [`Object.keys(foo)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)`.indexOf('Test 2')`. It will give you the index in the array of keys, which should be stable for the life of the object and property.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but could u please elaborate Object.keys(foo).indexOf('Test 2')? what is Object and foo?

Comment: `Object.keys` is a static method on the global `Object` object that returns an array containing all the keys in a particular object (hopefully you don't object to how many times I've used object in that sentence). If `foo = {'Test': 1, 'Test 2': 2}`, then `Object.keys(foo)` will return `['Test', 'Test 2']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function indexOfAtrr(obj,attr) {
    i = 0;
    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
        if (key == attr) return i;
        i++;
    });
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Would suggest you add an explanation of why this is a valid solution. More importantly though, OP requested an answer in pure JavaScript, not jQuery.